# pathogen plugin installation alternative syntax

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I was looking for some syntax highlighting goodness for [**handlebars in vim**](https://github.com/nono/vim-handlebars) and the installation instructions say to do this...

```
cd ~/.vim/
git submodule add git://github.com/nono/vim-handlebars.git bundle/handlebars
```

What is the purpose of this and how does it differ form just cloning the repository in the bundle directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Putting one's `~/.vim` under version control is trendy.
- Using Git for that is trendy.
- `git clone …` is a convenient, and trendy, way to install a plugin but…
- cloning another Git repo inside of a Git repo can become messy.
- Git submodules allow you to do just that, in a less messy manner.
- And they are trendy.

[This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1462754/546861) explains submodules briefly and [this page of the Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) gives you more bang for your bucks.

Comment: hahah... so I get to be like 2% more hipster now?

Comment: With a plugin called "handlebars" your hipsterness bumps by 10 % at least. But I prefered them when they were underground.